# How to define Widget class for toolbar with buttons in Dojo Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget, dijit.form

I will create new class - toolbar with standard action buttons **( Add, Edit, Remove, Refresh )**. I wrote simple class for this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dijit/Toolbar",
    // Template for new widget
    "dojo/text!/ui/widgets/StandardToolbar.html",
    // Load dijit/form/Button widget as dependency for parsing template
    "dijit/form/Button"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Toolbar, templateString){
    return declare("app.StandardToolbar", [
        _WidgetBase,
        _TemplatedMixin,
        _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
        Toolbar
    ], {
        templateString: templateString
    });
});
```

Template extended from basic toolbar:

```
<div class="dijit" role="toolbar" tabIndex="${tabIndex}" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
  <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-point="addButton">Add</button>
  <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-point="editButton">Edit</button>
  <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-point="removeButton">Remove</button>
  <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-point="refreshButton">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

And it's not working . Buttons in the toolbar render as the standard HTML buttons not Dojo widgets. What I doing wrong ?

Comment: you wont ot create your own dijit/toolbar ?

Comment: could you show us how you instantiate your widget !? also is ther an error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just missed to set the dojo type `data-dojo-type='dijit/Toolbar'` in your template containerNode div .

You have to set the :

```
<div data-dojo-type='dijit/Toolbar' class="dijit" role="toolbar" tabIndex="${tabIndex}" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
```

```js
require(["dijit/Toolbar", "dijit/form/Button","dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Toolbar, Button, Parser) {
  Parser.parse();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="claro">
  <div class="dijit" data-dojo-type='dijit/Toolbar' role="toolbar" tabIndex="${tabIndex}" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
  <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-point="addButton">Add</button>
  <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-point="editButton">Edit</button>
  <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-point="removeButton">Remove</button>
  <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-point="refreshButton">Refresh</button>
</div>
</div>
```